# Powershell Get 32 bit Counter from a 64bit machine

Tags: powershell, 32bit-64bit

I am trying to query a 32bit perfmon counter on a 64bit machine.

Buy default 32bit counter on a 64 bit machine is not visible through get-counter query executed form a 32bit machine.

Any workaround? Only WMI is enabled and no WINRM.

```
$Counters = "\App Virt Client Cache\Cache size (MB)"
(Get-Counter -Counter $Counters -ComputerName test1 -SampleInterval 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).CounterSamples
```

Comment: which counter are you looking for. What do you write so far.

Comment: $Counters = "\App Virt Client Cache\Cache size (MB)" (Get-Counter -Counter $Counters -ComputerName test1 -SampleInterval 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).CounterSamples

Answer (score 0):

The performance counter WMI classes have naming starting `Win32_PerfFormattedData_` with the remained or the name based on the name of the counter object.

Therefore you should be able to find the right WMI class by starting with:

```
Get-WmiObject -computer test1 -list "win32_PerfFormattedData_*" | Format-Table Name
```

and looking for the right class name. The individual counters will be properties of the WMI Object. Where a counter has instances there will be multiple instances of the WMI class (with the instance name being the `Name` property's value).

If you cannot find the right class, also consider looking at the raw classes (containing the raw numbers which you'll need to process depending on the type of counter. Eg. you need to derive the rate on a counter documented as the rate of something): prefix is `Win32_PerfRawData_`.

See MSDN for documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa392738%28v=vs.85%29.aspx